# How to remove some connected components in python?

Tags: python, ndimage

Consider a binarized image, I use `scipy.ndimage.label()` on it and then apply the `find_objects()` on the result.

Now I've got a tuple list consists of N tuples, each of them is two slice, like:

```
index  value
 0   (slice(0, 21, None) slice(0, 12, None)) 
 1   (slice(0, 42, None) slice(7, 31, None))
 .   (...., ....)
```

which describes a x-y boundary coordinate due to the connected component.

Take index 0 tuple as an example:

`slice(0, 21, None)` means the row number is from 0~21 and

`slice(0, 12, None)` means the column number is from 0~12.

So we will know that this cc's area is `21 * 12 = 252`.

Now I wanna remove those connected components whose area are smaller than 300.

I already know to do this iterating over all of them.
I would like to do it in a more efficient way; does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Please, don't post the answer inside the question. Write an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to do that before... But it needs 8 hours for me whose rep is lower than 10....Anyway, I'll edit it and thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code will solve my problem:

```
def CC(Map):
    label_img, cc_num = ndimage.label(Map)
    CC = ndimage.find_objects(label_img)
    cc_areas = ndimage.sum(Map, label_img, range(cc_num+1))
    area_mask = (cc_areas < 1500)
    label_img[area_mask[label_img]] = 0
return label_img, CC
```

area_mask[label_img] is the most important mask trick in my opnion.